# Data extraction from student identification card

Tags: flutter, image-processing, data-extraction

I am doing a mobile application using flutter and need to scan a student identification card.

Most of the libraries I found are for nationality identification cards, so I would like to customize one for myself. Are there any customizable libraries that can be used?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.